# How could I test ClassNotFoundException is being thrown?

Tags: java, mockito, classnotfoundexception, powermock

I have question that similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986195/how-could-i-test-classnotfoundexception-using-mockito/) where I have the following class:

```
public class FileClass {
    public void funcB() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

I would like to test whether `ClassNotFoundException` will be thrown when `funcB()` is called. Thus I have this test code:

```
public class TestFileClass {
    @Test(expected=ClassNotFoundException.class)
    public void testFuncB() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        FileClass fc = Mockito.spy(new FileClass());
        Mockito.doThrow(new ClassNotFoundException())
        .when(fc).funcB();
    }
}
```

But the test were failed due to following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Any clue how could I test `ClassNotFoundException` in `funcB()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're testing a method invocation on an instance of type `FileClass`, don't mock the instance. Just create an actual instance and call the method.

```
@Test(expected = ClassNotFoundException.class)
public void testFuncB() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    FileClass fc = new FileClass();
    fc.funcB();
}
```

Mocking is meant for things that you know ([would]) work but don't want to setup.

As @dzezzz states in the comments, a `ClassNotFoundException` (is that really the exception you want to test?) could be thrown in the `FileClass` constructor. If that is not something that should happen and that you want to test, you can set up the following test so that it is only expected from the method invocation

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test()
public void testFuncB() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    FileClass fc = new FileClass();
    exception.expect(ClassNotFoundException.class);
    fc.funcB();
}
```

The test will pass only if a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown *after* the `ExpectedException#expect()` call.

Comment: If this exception is thrown in FileClass constructor such test will pass. Better use ExpectedException @Rule and expect exception right before the call of funcB.

Comment: @dzezzz Good point. `ClassNotFoundExcepton` can pretty much happen anywhere, but it does help to restrict the scope we want to test. OP really shouldn't be testing that exception though IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you test FileClass then don't mock it. You should mock the classes which are used by FileClass.
If you don't want that the exception will come out from test method.
There is a solution:

```
@Test(expected = ClassNotFoundException.class)
public void testFuncB(){
    try{
        FileClass fc = new FileClass();
        fc.funcB();
        fail();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
    }
}
```

In this solution you catch the exception if it is thrown but your test fails when it isn't.

Comment: Remove the `expected`.